# Define types for a nested object - TS

Tags: typescript, types

I have an object of URLs. The URL is requested by pressing a button. I have 3 buttons: <kbd>Input</kbd>, <kbd>Output</kbd>  and <kbd>StandardReport</kbd>.

<kbd>StandardReport</kbd> will open a window which has 3 buttons inside it named <kbd>Define</kbd>, <kbd>Validate</kbd> and <kbd>Refresh</kbd>.

```js
export interface StandardReport {
    define: string;
    validate: string;
    refresh: string;
}


interface GeneratedFilesURL {
  inputs: string;
  outputs: string;
  standardReport: StandardReport;
}

export const GENERATED_FILES_URL: GeneratedFilesURL = {
  inputs: '/generated_files/input_consolidation',
  outputs: '/generated_files/output_consolidation',
  standardReport: {
    define: '/generated_files/standard_report_define',
    validate: '/generated_files/standard_report_validate',
    refresh: '/generated_files/standard_report_refresh',
  },
};

export type Source = 'inputs' | 'outputs' | StandardReport;
```

I access the URL using `GENERATED_FILES_URL[source]` where `source` can be <kbd>inputs</kbd> or <kbd>outputs</kbd>, I get `Type 'StandardReport' cannot be used as an index type.` and also as `GENERATED_FILES_URL.standardReport.define` or `GENERATED_FILES_URL.standardReport.validate`.

Could you please help me out with the exact type structure?

[Playground link](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjiAJnKWBKEADgPZRjIDeAUMnclhDKBAFzIDOYUoA5gNy16ANzgAbYDkjsuPEAKF0oTZRwAWM7n0EBfaqEixEKAOIQQ0OJCwAxYGIgcAqvgAyyCAA9I2DskIIZFgAPLJ8ADTImACeAHxUQqBEAK5gHJpyCnQkqSlpGdpCXJg4eISk5OzoJbgExGRgutT64NDwSGgYkAl0HEgguMAk6cggyQC2AEbQANoAuoLZuakjY1OzC4kgeasT01Dzi5wY2LXlDexr%204dCYMDjjgjijgXyN3RY9%20YcQyAAkiBiiAkLt1gdNh8voDfgAhMSYADWoOumz01ECgIoJgAogA5bH4ACCABVsQARAD6Nj%20rmxqApLlc7DMFigVggtnsjkZyAAvD1kEkVuwAOQAel45ks1gpzAcHDFQrAFIxHBIEikvxF4SEOTAO1FEqlbJlcscYr1eRVJEB6skVi1Ot6J1KdQqYHYNHoDCYLENktZ7Kwsq5CqBropyndFMYzAs2sUyFEGvZ-uNQZD8rF4dqkfq5ApyftkAT3uUMFUGmQ4oD0o5mfNObweej5crpeQOh1OkE1DA0SIKFQOSgHX5CIg0RIMGQLLrnPljN7qooauSo4gADVxK9eHzq0qOCLlzauJwIA4EHcbVUuih%20V76H1zINhuwZgBGcIAJjmTuQlrCsgn4-n%20WwGsBX7IL%20-5Nm6FyQZEMG3F8fTPCMMwih%202rVt%20IpgZCDzQjaAJAiC75fshhHfLC8IgEiFGgd2zSquqEAAHRiCQvAABQcBeEBXr8Mxrhu25iHMACUvZAA)

Please navigate to the errors tab to get the error

Answer (score 1):

for your `Source` type, you actually want to have something like `export type Source = keyof GeneratedFilesURL`;

and for your interface (since you want to lookup by string), easiest is to extend it from `Record`

```
interface GeneratedFilesURL extends Record<sting, any> {
    ....
}
```

then you can easily do what you want;

```
export const myType: Source = 'standardReport';
const bla = GENERATED_FILES_URL[myType].define
```

Comment: That actually fixed a lot of things. Thank you. I have another variable called selection which is an object and it accepts a source value which can be either 'inputs' or 'outputs' only.  I get this error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'State'.

Comment: selection has a type called State which is 
export interface State {
  scenarios: number[];
  outputs: number[];
  inputs: number[];
  standardReport: number[];
  timescales: string[];
  dimensionInstances: number[];
  dimensionBlanks: number[];
}

Comment: please create a [replicable test bed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZRkyQBNMoSAlYSWOAbwCg4W4Th1lgAuOAZxhRkAcwDczVgDdMAGwRlUvAUKRiJLKB018AFksEjxAX0bJUGHHgDiwJGkyoSAMQQzgfAKqUAMnFCpSPjhqbGgSAB5lEQAaOGIATwA+BglkMABXGD59FTUWCEyMrJzDCQFiMgpqWhheQgryKhpoGGNGUBq4UKQBOCsAUQA5fsoAQQAVfoARAH0nAElvfvwZr29eGzsoB2BnV3c1uABeFJY0zOy4AHIAemFbe0cZzjc+G-OYGe6+CDkFBAgSCu0QkBRgRUut3uWx2JGe+zeYKKX0BPz+DgBQJBLHKpEa1RavCYrDYHC4vChD22Txe7huuMqcM0NRm7E4dmB6jg0nRimudypsPhr3pRDxFBmzJaMx58h2nJJmnQ2j0-Ohj12wrpDMakuasD1yvcOgVcCMIKM4g6LTgMHiYDw+AKUFwxzgAGtgPEIOg+oLHC5XmtREA)

Comment: [Here it is](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#). Works good here, but on the UI get an error for selection[source].TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'State'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'State'.

Comment: that link doesnt work. it seems like you have defined the index of seletion to be string (instead of Source)

Comment: I edited the OP to add the link as I was unable to send it here. Please navigate to the errors tab to get the error

Comment: Could you help me out on this please?

Comment: @a2441918 your link is still broken

Comment: Updated the link.